# File Uploaded with no errors, doesn't appear in directory?

Tags: php

I'm trying to upload a file via PHP using a form. Here is the PHP I have used in order to start the upload:

```
if(isset($_FILES['image'])){

        $target_dir = "/var/www/html/uploads/";
        $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["image"]["name"]);
        $uploadOk = 1;
        $imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        // Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
        if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
            $check = getimagesize($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"]);
            if($check !== false) {
                echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
                $uploadOk = 1;
            } else {
                echo "File is not an image.";
                $uploadOk = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    //if there is an error...
    else
    {
        //set that to be the returned message
        echo "Ooops!  Your upload triggered the following error";
        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    }
```

There are no errors/notices with

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors','On');
```

or in the apache2 error logs. The permissions of the folder in /var/www/html/uploads is 777 (for development only), so it is writeable.

Comment: Where's your `move_uploaded_file()` function?

Answer (score 1):

This is the way to upload file in the directory A folder named "UPLOAD" should be there in ht docs to see the uploaded files.

```
<?php
   if(isset($_FILES['image'])){
      $errors= array();
      $file_name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
      $file_size =$_FILES['image']['size'];
      $file_tmp =$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
      $file_type=$_FILES['image']['type'];
      $file_ext=strtolower(end(explode('.',$_FILES['image']['name'])));

      $expensions= array("jpeg","jpg","png");

      if(in_array($file_ext,$expensions)=== false){
         $errors[]="extension not allowed, please choose a JPEG or PNG file.";
      }

      if($file_size > 2097152){
         $errors[]='File size must be excately 2 MB';
      }

      if(empty($errors)==true){
         move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"upload/".$file_name);
         echo "Success";
      }
      else{
         print_r($errors);
      }
   }
?>
<html>
   <body>

      <form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
         <input type="file" name="image" />
         <input type="submit"/>
      </form>

   </body>
</html>
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you should move uploaded file to $target_dir. 
use move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"], $target_dir."new_file_name")